# What is the convention for printing variable names?

Tags: python, conventions

When a variable is referred in documetation string, ``` `` ``` is used:

```py
def func(var):
    """
    Parameter ``var`` is referred in a documetation string.
    """
```

**What is the convention for printing a variable name?** (or using in a string to be shown to the user, such as exception's message) Would it be the same:

```py
def func(var):
    if not check1(var):
        raise Exception("parameter ``var`` has to be...")
    if not check2(var):
        logger.warn("parameter ``var`` is...")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just generate some exceptions in the interpreter:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sdf' is not defined
>>> mystr = 'sdf'
>>> mystr.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

As we can see, a common practice for exception messages seems to be single quotes, as in `'name'`:

```
NameError: name 'sdf' is not defined
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

**Even better example by the OP (@Itay):**

```
>>> def a(d):
...     pass
... 
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'
```

Comment: @Coal_ True, reworded to avoid declaring a standard where there isn't really one set in stone.

Comment: @bgse Please note that non of the examples you have given are variable names.

Comment: @Italy The point is (I believe) that they're referencing an object at runtime.

Comment: Okay, I think I have an example to show why it should be a single quote:

def a(d):
    pass
a()
TypeError: a() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'

Comment: @Itay Indeed, best example by a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. I like using single backticks or even single quotes:

```
"parameter `var` has to be [...]"
"parameter 'var' has to be [...]"
```

Double backticks hurt readability, in my opinion. By the way, you don't *have* to use double backticks to reference variables in docstrings. I know Sphinx and most IDEs / code analysis tools require double backticks, but you may as well stick to quotes (unless you have hundreds of objects and have to use autodoc).